# How extend main class to use Sherlock Action Bar and PhoneGap together on Android

Tags: android, cordova, actionbarsherlock

i have a problem, i want to use Sherlock Action Bar and PhoneGap together on a Android Project.

I read i another stack overflow post that Android not support more than one extension.

This is my working code.

```
package com.inmo.mobile;

// import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

//public class Inmo extends DroidGap {
//
//    @Override
//    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
//        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 5000);
//    }
//    
//}

public class Inmo extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.favorites) {
            //startActivity(new Intent(this, FavoritesActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(this, "favoritos pulsado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.preferences) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "configuración pulsado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The PhoneGap code it's commented, boths codes works when one it's commented and the other not, so i need two combine boths and extend the main class to sherlock and phonegap (to included to cordova webview).

This it's possible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the static attachment method? Eg:

```
public class Inmo extends DroidGap implements ActionBar.TabListener, 
        OnCreateOptionsMenuListener, OnMenuItemSelectedListener {
    private ActionBarSherlock mSherlock;

    protected final ActionBarSherlock getSherlock() {
        if (mSherlock == null) {
            mSherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);
        }
        return mSherlock;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Did you make sure to import from the actionbarsherlock packages? E.g. `com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.OnMenuItemSelectedListener`

Comment: Check this out: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-960. It says that you must hardcode the res/ references. E.g. `sherlock.setContentView(0x7f030000)`. You must also call `super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", true)`.